# Mathematics cases in Google Documents

Tags: google-docs, formatting

How can I write mathematics equations with multiple cases in Google Documents?

I can't get the code below to work. This is how I would create it in LaTeX:

```
\begin{cases}
    0               & n = 0\\
    1               & n = 1\\
    f(n-1) + f(n-2) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
```

It should result in:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cases` isn't natively supported by Google Documents as you can see in the [list of supported LaTeX operators](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/160749?hl=en)<sup>†</sup>. Some [projects](https://code.google.com/p/latex-lab/) try to extend GDoc's LaTeX capabilities.

---

<sup>†</sup> Not at present, but Wayback Machine has a copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20160409034821/https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160749?hl=en